# Starling library - Sprite dissapeared from stage and I don't know why

Tags: image, actionscript-3, flash, flash-builder, starling-framework

The code for the question is [here](https://github.com/eamonwhiter73/avoidergame) - I am using Flash Builder 4.7, I will also post all the relevant code now:

**Game.as** (might be something wrong here)

```
package
{
import Classes.AvatarEnemy;

//import starling.animation.Juggler;
//import starling.core.Starling;
import starling.display.Sprite;

import flash.geom.Point;
import flash.display.Bitmap;
import flash.display.BitmapData;
import flash.ui.Mouse;
import flash.ui.MouseCursorData;

    public class Game extends Sprite
    {
        //private var juggler:Juggler = Starling.juggler;

        [Embed(source="Classes/Avatarpic.png")]
        private const Cursor:Class;

        public var enemy:AvatarEnemy;

        public function Game() 
        {   
            enemy = new AvatarEnemy();
            addChild(enemy);

            //var counter:int;

            /*juggler.delayCall(function():void {

                if(enemy.hitTest(cursor_D.hotSpot, true)) {
                    var score:int = counter;
                    trace(score);
                };

                counter++;
            }, 1.0);*/

            function createCustomCursor():void
            {
                var cursorBitmaps:Vector.<BitmapData> = new Vector.<BitmapData>();
                cursorBitmaps.push((new Cursor() as Bitmap).bitmapData);

                var mouseCursorData:MouseCursorData = new MouseCursorData();
                mouseCursorData.data        = cursorBitmaps;
                mouseCursorData.frameRate   = 30;
                mouseCursorData.hotSpot     = new Point(0, 0);

                Mouse.registerCursor("customCursor", mouseCursorData);
                Mouse.cursor = "customCursor";
            }

            createCustomCursor();
        }
    }
}
```

**Startup.as** (shouldn't be anything wrong here)

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import starling.core.Starling;
    import Game;

    [SWF(width="400", height="300", frameRate="60", backgroundColor="#ffffff")]
    public class Startup extends Sprite
    {
        private var _starling:Starling;

        public function Startup()
        {
            _starling = new Starling(Game, stage);
            _starling.start();
        }
    }
}
```

**AvatarEnemy.as** (might be something wrong here)

```
package Classes
{

    import starling.display.Image;
    import starling.display.Sprite;
    import starling.textures.Texture;

    public class AvatarEnemy extends Sprite
    {
        [Embed(source='Enemypic.png')]
        private static var Enemypic:Class;

        private var texture:Texture = Texture.fromBitmap(new Enemypic());

        private var image:Image = new Image(texture);

        public function AvatarEnemy() 
        {                   
            image.x = 0;
            image.y = 200;

            addChild(image);            
        }
    }
}
```

All of the code at the end of `Game.as` is me trying to make the cursor a certain image - I also need help with that too. But right now - the `enemy` object isn't being added to the stage for some reason, despite the fact that I use `addChild(enemy)`. Anyone know why? Thanks.

Comment: What's `AvatarEnemy`? Where you get it from? There might be numerous reasons.. First it's good to wait for Starling initialization before doing anything else :)

Comment: @AndreyPopov thanks for your comment - AvatarEnemy is a class for an enemy object (see Game.as) - when I instantiate it - it puts a smiley face at `image.x` and `image.y` - I have since changed my code a little bit - but I am still having the same problem...I have isolated it further - I'm going to ask another stack question (which gets more to the root of the problem) and ill post the link here - give me a few minutes. What do you mean by wait for Starling initialization...are you saying do all the "work" in `Startup.as`?

Comment: @AndreyPopov check out this question - it is where i am at now with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23784027/starling-library-when-i-try-and-change-cursor-to-image-it-doesnt-work-and